# Insert and retrieve a matrix in a database

Tags: c++, database, matrix, vector, blob

I have a an object of type `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` and a `bool` value in my class. The content of the vector of vector is always like this structure (120 lines of 4 values and followed by 50 lines of 3 values):

```
-78.45 5120 45.369 7.456
-0.140 1.012 1.161 7.456
-4.4287 8.963 1.121 7898
-8.753 8.159 3.852 2.415
0.000 2.456 4.655 6.041
0.000 3.132 8.275 1.788
7.489 8.056 7.288 5.698
4.050 7.456 7.340 2.025
0.090 9.478 9.395 6.416
1.132 6.866 8.450 2.126
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
6.222 5.142 7.596 0.56
9.121 2.256 5.641
8.896 1.488 2.858
7.489 8.056 7.288
4.050 7.456 7.340
0.090 9.478 9.395
7.489 8.056 7.288
4.050 7.456 7.340
0.090 9.478 9.395
```

How can I store my matrix to retrieve the same `vector<std::vector<float>>` when I load it from database. My problem is I don't know how can I "know" when I am on a line of 4 values or 3 values. My initial idea was to store the object using boost but I can't add this library. I am in C++98. As I can't use boost, I think I should store in one line the values. But, what is the algorithm to rebuild a vector of vector of float with 4 values to 120 first lines and 3 values to the end of the database ?

Can I have a sample code?

Comment: ***My problem is I don't know how can I "know" when I am on a line of 4 values or 3 values.*** Should that matter? Use std::getline() and std::stringstream.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation:

1. Read a line of text from the file. If there are not more lines, you are done.
2. Construct a `std::istringstream` from the line of text. Keep reading numbers from the `std::istringstream` until there are no more numbers.
3. Gather all the numbers from the above step in a `std::vector<float>`.
4. Add the `std::vector<float>` corresponding to a line to the higher level `std::vector`.

I was tempted to post the code but I refrained. That would be too much spoonfeeding, IMO.